# javascript using variables if statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Actual code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YidX3.jpg
Actual Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s95TP.jpg

I have 5 variables: va1, va2, va3, va4 and va5, that can have values > 0. I want to calculate the other variables that are missing. All of them properly work from html number field and update manually if I check and update one by one.

```
for (i=1; i <= 5; i++) {
    alert('va'+i); //these alert write va1 to va5 correct
}

if('va'+i >0) { //but thia doesn't work, even if I define variable x='va'+i;
    alert("bigger"); // even if statement is true ex va1 > 0 the if statement won't do it
}

//if I do it by hand:
if(va1 > 0) {
    alert("Bigger"); //these one works but not i want to write 42 variables by hand
}
```

So any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand nothing.

Comment: i need the if to automaticaly check the va1 to va5 values is bigger than 0 inside the for loop, inside if statement the value needs to be that inserted by the for loop as "va"+i(increment), I tried 2 ways to work but they only appear in console right but cant use it on the if statement besides the statement is true

Comment: @CrutchMaster agree. This question totally destroys my mind...

Comment: @Simaomp please add HTML to your example and... What are you trying to achieve? What is the final goal?

Comment: for what u need the html part thats is ok. the problem is in javascript im telling i get the value right and if i do if(va1 >0) that is true but if i do if("va"+i > o) that doesnt work i need that va1 is automatically added by the for loop 

<td><input name="vu1" type="number" id="vu1" style="width: 40px;" /></td>
                    <td><input name="va1" type="number" id="va1" style="width: 70px;" /></td>

Comment: are there many elements va1 va2 va3... or is it a single element va1 with a string of many numbers?

Comment: as a single element. <td><input name="vu5" type="number" id="vu5" style="width: 40px;" /></td>
                    <td><input name="va5" type="number" id="va5" style="width: 70px;" /></td>

dont have knowledge to make that in a array. But i can try it. The same problem will appear that i need to automatically update the value of each position of the array and for that i will need the auto increment so it updates all the valyes in different postion of arays and it seems that is not possible to use an string with a number in for and if loops

Comment: Improved spelling, grammar and clarity. May need additional clarity from the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check value by value and do something then:

```
const arrOfVa = []
for (let i=1;i<=5;i++){
   arrOfVa.push(document.getElementById('va'+i).value);
}

arrOfVa.forEach(va => {
   if (va > 0){
   // your code here
  }
});
```

If you want to check that every value is greater than zero then:

```
const arrOfVa = []
for (let i=1;i<=5;i++){
   arrOfVa.push(document.getElementById('va'+i).value);
}

if (arrOfVa.every(va => va > 0)){
   // your code here
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help. It appears an error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: arrOfVa is not defined
    at depreciacoes (fgcalc.php:201)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (fgcalc.php:125)

Comment: the same error appears dont know why. 

`if(va1>0){

       alert("Bigger");

   } else{


   }

    
    
   for (let i=1;i<=5;i++){

   arrOfVa.push(document.getElementById('va'+i).value);

        }

    if (arrOfVa.every(va => va > 0)){

         alert("Bigger than 0 ");

    }`

Comment: skipped the initialization of array, edited to add it

Comment: no error now but the same problem. statement is correct but dont execute it

Comment: please put a console.log(arrOfVa) after the for and let me know what it outputs

Comment: Actual code: https://imgur.com/a/RmVhdpI
Actual Output: https://imgur.com/a/z5oaSsb

Comment: ok so arrOfVa.push(document.getElementById('va'+i).value); is returning empty for va2, va3 ... Do they have values on  your html?

Comment: no, i just test for va1, because not all will be full, but is ok. Your code can store all the values as fine but still cant acess them to compare if its higher than 0. The if statement is still the problem and it's all correct the code dont know why doesnt work....

Comment: if(arrOfVa[i] > 0) inside a for loop?

Comment: oh ok, what if i want to not every position of array. One by one if va1 is writen but va2 is empty it appears a message va1 higher than 0? Check each one with the if statement inside for loop? 

if (arrOfVa[i] >0 ){
   console.log(i + "is bigger than 0 ");   
}

Comment: then you can use the "If you want to check value by value and do something" part (ofc you're free to use a classic for rather than a forEach)

Answer (score 0):

`if (document.getElementById(va+i).value > 0) {`

Comment: would work but the va part need to have "va"+1 "va"+2 etc